# Does simultaneous popen and fgets block across threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, popen, fgets

I am trying to extract data from multiple shell commands. Each of these 5 commands take around 3 seconds to run, so I thought I'd run them in parallel. I did it like this, where `generators` is a vector of function pointers.

```cpp
std::vector<std::future<Table>> tables;
for (size_t i = 0; i < generators.size(); i++)
{
    tables.push_back(std::async(std::launch::async, generators[i]));
}
for (size_t i = 0; i < tables.size(); i++)
{
    tables[i].wait();
}
// And then use the result with tables[i].get()
```

Each of the generators eventually calls the following method. It executes a command and return the output lines.

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> exec(std::string const& cmd)
{
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    std::vector<std::string> result;
    std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(&pclose)> pipe(popen(cmd.c_str(), "r"), pclose);
    if (pipe)
    {
        std::string line;
        while (fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr)
        {
            line += buffer.data();
            if (line.back() == '\n')
            {
                line.pop_back();
                result.push_back(std::move(line));
            }
        }
        if (!line.empty())
        {
            result.push_back(std::move(line));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Both this multithreaded version, and my original sequential, version takes around 15 seconds to complete.

Does the `fgets` call on a `popen` pipe block across threads? And if so, is there a way I can work around it?

Comment: From [the doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) of the `std::async` overload you are using: "f **might** be executed in another thread or it might be run synchronously when the resulting std::future is queried for a value."

Comment: Thanks @Frank, I saw that now. I tried calling `std::async` with `std::launch::async` to make it run on a separate thread. I'll update the question.

Comment: You could run `sleep 3; echo "done"` (or something similar that your shell understands) as shell code to reduce the scope and easily provide a [mcve]. Just to answer your question, no, neither of the two calls generally blocks everything else. Having such a contention on non-shared resources could be considered a performance bug in the C libs and/or OS underneath.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I never thought about it, but it was the commands that couldn't be run in parallel! I tried your suggestion, and it ran in 3.2 seconds. Thank you!